# DataAnnotation: Como validar propriedade "e-mail", verificar se existe ou não no banco, com atributo sem ser no cliente e sim no Servidor

Tags: c#, validação, view, model-validation, dataannotations

Eu tenho uma aplicação em camadas, e na minha camada de apresentação, tenho uma `ViewModel` que é `UsuarioViewModel` dentro desta tenho um *property* chamada `public email {get; set;}`.

Já esta validando através de *DataAnnotation* tudo corretamente, eu si preciso soluciona uma questão, como eu valido, sem ser no cliente em sim no servidor, se o *e-mail* que esta sendo cadastrado já existe no meu banco de dados!.

Tentei fazer um atributo de validação customizado mas sem sucesso, minha simples questão é : Como eu valido no servidor e mando a mensagem de "Email já cadastrado" do mesmo jeito que já existe os atributos *Required, Min, Max, Date, CreditCard*, entendem.

Só uma observação:

Talvez vocês se pergunte por que não faz a validação por *Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive*, minha resposta é: Pode ter usuários que desabilitem a execução de comandos Java Script no browser entendem, é por isso.

Visto que quando o usuário preenche o campo email no form o controller vai dar como *True* na minha linha `ModedelState.IsValid`, como eu valido neste caso?

**UsuarioViewModel.cs**:

```
public class UsuarioViewModel : BaseModel
{
    [DisplayName("Código")]
    public override int id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe seu o nome completo")]
    public string nomeCompleto { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Login")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o login")]
    [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "O login deve ter 8 ou mais caracteres")]
    public string login { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Senha")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a senha")]
    [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "A senha deve ter 8 ou mais caracteres")]
    public string senha { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email")]               
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Informe um email válido")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Chave de Criptgrafia")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe uma palavra ou frase pquena para chave criptografia")]
    public string chaveSimetrica { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data de Cadastro")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a data de cadastro")]        
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime dataCriacao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

}
```

**UsuarioController.cs**:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AdicionaUsuario([Bind(Exclude = "id")] UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();            

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        SetModel(usuario, usuarioViewModel);
        _usuarioService.adicionaUsuario(usuario);

        return RedirectToAction("ListaUsuario");
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditaUsuario(UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        SetModel(usuario, usuarioViewModel);
        _usuarioService.editaUsuario(usuario);

        return RedirectToAction("ListaUsuario");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que o asp net mvc valide no cliente eu uso um atributo do tipo System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute em cima do campo email. Assim o mvc já cria a validação no cliente. Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="email invalido")]
    public string email { get; set; }
```

Segue o código que coloco no form da view para validar

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Já para validar no servidor você tem a opção de validar com alguma chamada ajax disparada no evento onBlur do controle ou .blur do jquery passando o email e validando no servidor. Caso o email já esteja cadastrado você exibe uma mensagem informando. Essa é a maneira que dá uma melhor usabilidade ao sistema.
Mas caso você deseje validar no servidor somente quando o form for submetido (maneira mais fácil), você poderá utilizar o seguinte código

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(modelo mod)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // valide aqui o email e mande de volta o erro através da linha abaixo
            ModelState.AddModelError("email", "Email já cadastrado");

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Obs.: usei o mvc 5 para o exemplo

Comment: Muito Legal funcionou!!!! sim... Marco... obrigadão pela dica!!!

Comment: @Rodrigo dê uma olhada em um post que fiz no meu blog e veja que tem uma técnica interessante em validar email ou outro atributo no lado do servidor de forma simples chamada remote validation http://blogdoquintal.net/2015/01/06/fazendo-validacao-ajax-no-servidor-com-asp-net-mvc/